# How do I share the same object between separate fast-api routers?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have an object that is a data-base adapter layer.

```
adapter = MyDBAdapter()
```

I would like to be able to pass an instance of that `adapter` object to both routes.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from .routers import foo, bar

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(foo.router)
app.include_router(bar.router)
```

For the sake of not having to instantiate two instances of the data-base connection, I was wondering if there was a pythonic fast-api way to pass in the `adapter` object reference?  Or would it make more sense to just instantiate it twice in both routes?